# From GAE to Cloudfoundry

Tags: java, google-app-engine, cloud, cloud-foundry

I'd like to know the main differences between CloudFoundry and Google App Engine for a personnal project.

I have a web application that currently runs on GAE and i'am thinking to move it to CloudFoundry for various technical reasons.

I'd like to use :

- Spring MVC & Spring Security.
- a full implementation of JPA instead of DataNucleus.
- mavenize my project properly, i can't make the maven-gae-plugin works.

Is CloudFoundry a good alternative to GAE in my case?
What is the complexity of the migration?

Thanks

Comment: http://blog.frankel.ch/first-try-with-cloudfoundry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It shouldn't be too hard to migrate the app.
http://blog.springsource.org/2011/11/10/using-cloud-foundry-services-with-spring-part-4-%E2%80%93-spring-profiles/ and the whole series of articles has lot of details on how to bind your Spring app to a cloudfoundry data source.

http://blog.springsource.com/2011/09/22/rapid-cloud-foundry-deployments-with-maven/ has details about the cloudfoundry maven plugin, for deployment

To migrate your data, you may want to use the remote api http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/remoteapi.html or bulkloader to export, then CloudFoundry Caldecott to import your data in CloudFoundry http://blog.cloudfoundry.com/post/12928974099/now-you-can-tunnel-into-any-cloud-foundry-data-service

http://start.cloudfoundry.com/frameworks/java/spring/spring.html the getting started in cloudfoundry for spring is a good place to start learning about deploying spring apps to cloudfoundry.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I can only answer the maven part: see this for a working multimodule example: https://github.com/leanengine/LeanEngine-Server

you must use it like this:

```
mvn gae:unpack  // downloads GAE classes to your maven repo
mvn clean install package 
cd lean-server-example
mvn gae:execute  // starts a local server
```